# Show component only once in React or React Native using localstorage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, local-storage, asyncstorage

I am have the following situation where I am trying to show a screen component just once and only once using localstorge. This one is driving me mental.

App.js

```
...

constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isLoading: false,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    if (AsyncStorage.getItem('key')) {
      AsyncStorage.getItem('key', (value) => {
        this.setState({isLoading: value})
        Alert.alert(JSON.stringify(value))
      });
      AsyncStorage.setItem('key', JSON.stringify(true))
    }
  }

  render() {
    if (!this.state.isLoading) {
      return <Search />
    }
    return <Root />
    }

...
```

Comment: AsyncStorage is well async you can't check presence of key this way `if (AsyncStorage.getItem('key')) {`

Comment: Ah, anywork around on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to slightly modify `componentDidMount` implementation and add another flag to component's state

```
constructor() {
   ...
   this.state = {
      isLoaded: false,
      wasShown: false
   }
}

componentDidMount() {
   AsyncStorage.getItem('key') // get key
     .then(wasShown => {
         if(wasShown === null) { // first time 
           // we need to save key for the next time
           AsyncStorage.setItem('key', '"true"')
         }

         this.setState({isLoaded: true, wasShown})
      })
  }

render() {
  const { isLoaded, wasShown } = this.state

  // you can't tell if this component was shown or not render nothing
  if(!isLoaded) { return null }

  if(!wasShown) {
    return <Search />
  } 

  return <Root/>
}
```

BTW if you include async/await support to your babel presets you could make this code way simpler

```
async componentDidMount() {
   const wasShown = await AsyncStorage.getItem('key') // get key

   if(wasShown === null) {
     await AsyncStorage.setItem('key', '"true"')
   }

   this.setState({isLoaded: true, wasShown}
  }
```

Comment: is this logical possible using redux persist? I can set the value using redux, but not sure how to go about handling the storage method for getting keys in redux persist

Comment: MB. I have never used redux-persist package.

Answer (score 0):

Show something else while you check storage for value. After you have got the value just set state and show your screen. In other words, you should open your screen component only after you know for sure that you have not shown the screen yet.

Answer (score 0):

```
AsyncStorage.getItem('isShown').then((value) => {
      if(value == null){
        // Whatever you want to do just once.
        AsyncStorage.setItem('isShown', 'sth');
      }
    });
```